# Trying to find the Eigenvectors for the specific Eigen Values

Tags: python, differential-equations, eigenvalue, eigenvector

We were given a set of equations which we had to convert into a matrix. We were also given the k, m1 and m2 frequency values. After solving for the eigen values and coressponding vectors we were asked to solve according to the specific eigen values we calculated!

I've been trying to solve for the specific eigen vectors using the eigen values I've calculated. I think I'm on the right track with my loop but I keep getting the

```
'object is not callable'
```

error, and when I change the () to [] I get a syntax error! I'm not sure what to do!
[My Code Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPD8j.png)

Comment: we are not sitting in the same room as you and we are not looking at your screen, nor have we developed the ability to read minds yet, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74209617/edit) your question and copy-paste your code and full error traceback into the question as text inside a code block so that people can find the problem.

Comment: Sorry! I added the photo of my code, I thought it uploaded but didn't! @AhmedAEK

Comment: based on your continous use of `disp` and parenthesis indexing i am guessing you are rewriting your code from matlab, in any case indexing in python is done using square brackets `[ ]`, but i won't be able to find any more problems from an image of code, [please copy-paste post code as text not as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) in the question so people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

For the future please add codeblocks in the question, as it makes it much easier for anyone to pick up your code and modify it.

I think the issue (at least the error you have right now) comes from the fact that you are accessing the values of the numpy array using `(i, i)` instead of `[i, i]`. The way you are writing it now, the interpretor expects a function to which you pass some parameters, not an array.

So change `eigenvectors(i, i)` to `eigenvectors[i, i]`.